# How can I retrieve data regarding screen views from the Google Analytics API

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-api, google-reporting-api

With use of the tracker in my mobile apps I'm retrieving data for every screen. Now there's one problem, I would like to request this data through the Google Analytics API.
I thought I could request this info with either the dimensions "ga:pageTitle" or "ga:pagePath". The data I'm receiving is pagetitle: "(not set)".
Is it even possible to retrieve data like that through the API or is it only visible through the Analytics website?

Any help is welcome. 
Thanks for any help or thought,

Bart

Answer (score 1):

ga:appViews is your friend ;-)

#### UPDATE

Starting from July 2013 ga:appViews has been deprecated and now you should use [ga:screenviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/apptracking#ga%3ascreenviews)